# select records that not exists in another table

Tags: oracle11g

I would like to get all values in x that do not exists in table TableA.

I've tried following queries that is returning blank.

```
select x.num from 
(
   select '888888' as num from dual union all
   select '111111' as num from dual
) x 
left outer join TableA a on (a.number = x.num)
where a.number is null


select x.num
FROM
(
    select '888888' as num from dual union all
    select '111111' as num from dual
) x
where x.num not in
(
    select a.number from TableA a where x.num = a.number
)
```

**Table**

```
| TableA.number |
-------------
  111111
  333333
```

The expected result is that only '888888' is returned in this case.

I can't see why this shouldn't work, where have i've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
with cte as
(
   select '888888' as num from dual union all
   select '111111' as num from dual
)  
select cte.num 
from cte
left join TableA a on (a.number = cte.num)
where a.number is null
```